# System.Threading.Timer stuck for some time when server has load

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

We have below class members for timer:

```cs
private Timer _activityTimer;
```

Instantiating this timer variable in one method:

```
_activityTimer = 
    new Timer(async (timerState) => await UpdateActivityAsync(_ipAddress), null, new Random().Next(1, 15000), 15000);
```

But this did not calling periodically when server has load.

It is showing below log in serilog:

1. Starting HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle with {InitialCount} items
2. Ending HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle after {ElapsedMilliseconds}ms - processed: {DisposedCount} items - remaining: {RemainingItems} items

Comment: Are you aware that the `System.Timer` does not support async? It doesn't wait until the complete async action is finished. I don't know what `UpdateActivityAsync` does, but it might be running more than ones.

Comment: @Jeroen van Langen and Guru Stron
 I am using System.Threading.Timer

Comment: What does `did not calling periodically when server has load.` mean? What do those counts mean and what does `UpdateActivityAsync` do? `System.Threading.Timer` won't wait for the callback to complete. It will keep firing until it stops. This means that multiple `UpdateActivityAsync` calls may be active at the same time. If you want to avoid that use eg an ActionBlock to execute only one activity at a time, in the order they're posted

Comment: `System.Threading.Timer` runs on a thread from the thread pool. If all threads in the thread pool are busy, then the timer will wait for a thread to free. I would suggest manually creating a new thread and running an infinite loop inside of it using `PeriodicTimer` class.

Comment: Please post minimal code that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To handle async periodic callback, I would use `System.Threading.PeriodicTimer`. This way the execution of the next `UpdateActivityAsync` will not begin until the last one is done. If you still face thread pool starvation issue, you could manually create an additional thread in which you run the timer.

```cs
class Example {
    private PeriodicTimer _activityTimer;
    private IPAddress     _ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.1");

    public void StartTimer() {
        // Starting the timer, but not awaiting to not block the calling thread
        // If you still face thread pool starvation issue, you could manually create an additional thread here
        StartTimerLoopAsync();
    }

    public void StopTimer() {
        _activityTimer.Dispose();
    }

    private async Task StartTimerLoopAsync() {
        _activityTimer = new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(15000));
        while (await _activityTimer.WaitForNextTickAsync()) {
            await UpdateActivityAsync(_ipAddress);
        }
    }

    private async Task UpdateActivityAsync(IPAddress ipAddress) {
        await Task.Delay(500); // Simulate some IO
        Console.WriteLine(ipAddress);
    }
}
```

---

*UPDATE for .NET Core 3.1*

Instead of `PeriodicTimer` you could simply use `Task.Delay` (it's not very accurate, but good enough for your use case I believe):

```cs
class Example {
    private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource = new ();
    private IPAddress               _ipAddress               = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.1");

    public void StartTimer() {
        // Starting the timer, but not awaiting to not block the calling thread
        // If you still face thread pool starvation issue, you could manually create an additional thread here
        StartTimerLoopAsync();
    }

    public void StopTimer() {
        _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    }

    private async Task StartTimerLoopAsync() {
        await Task.Delay(new Random().Next(1, 15000)); // System.Threading.Timer first delay
        
        while (!_cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested) {
            // run the Delay and UpdateActivityAsync simultaneously and wait for both
            var delayTask = Task.Delay(15000, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);
            await UpdateActivityAsync(_ipAddress, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);
            await delayTask;
        }
    }

    private async Task UpdateActivityAsync(IPAddress ipAddress, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        await Task.Delay(1500, cancellationToken); // Simulate some IO
        Console.WriteLine(ipAddress);
    }
}
```

---

*UPDATE*

You could also create your own async Timer:

```cs
class Example : IDisposable {
    private AsyncTimer<Example>? _timer;
    public  IPAddress            IpAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.1");

    public void StartTimer() {
        if (_timer is not null) {
            return;
        }

        _timer = new AsyncTimer<Example>(async (state, ct) => await UpdateActivityAsync(state.IpAddress, ct), this, new Random().Next(1, 15000), 15000);
    }

    public void StopTimer() {
        _timer?.Stop();
    }

    private async Task UpdateActivityAsync(IPAddress ipAddress, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        await Task.Delay(500, cancellationToken); // Simulate some IO
        Console.WriteLine(ipAddress);
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        _timer?.Dispose();
    }
}

class AsyncTimer<T> : IDisposable {
    public delegate Task AsyncTimerDelegate(T state, CancellationToken cancellationToken);

    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource = new();
    private readonly AsyncTimerDelegate      _timerCallback;
    private readonly TimeSpan                _dueTime;
    private readonly TimeSpan                _interval;
    private readonly T                       _state;

    public AsyncTimer(AsyncTimerDelegate timerCallback, T state, int dueTime, int interval) {
        _timerCallback = timerCallback;
        _state         = state;
        _dueTime       = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(dueTime);
        _interval      = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(interval);

        // Starting the timer, but not awaiting to not block the calling thread
        // If you still face thread pool starvation issue, you could manually create an additional thread here
        StartTimerLoopAsync();
    }

    public void Stop() {
        _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    }

    private async Task StartTimerLoopAsync() {
        await Task.Delay(_dueTime);

        while (!_cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested) {
            // run the Delay and UpdateActivityAsync simultaneously and wait for both
            var delayTask = Task.Delay(_interval, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);
            await _timerCallback.Invoke(_state, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);
            await delayTask;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        _cancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.Threading.PeriodicTimer` is available since .NET 6, while OP has `asp.net-core-3.1` tag.

Comment: I am using .NetCore3.1

Comment: @DipakShinde I've provided the solution for .Net Core 3.1

Comment: @DipakShinde .NET Core 3.1 reached End Of Life last week. It won't even get security updates from now on. You still haven't explained what's going on. There are solutions that can solve the actual problem without a lot of complex coding